# Automatically add a tag for all Application Insights telemetry from .Net Applications

Tags: azure-application-insights

We have several .Net 5 projects / applications that are logically grouped together and I'd like to globally apply a tag to each telemetry sent from each application depending on its logical group identifier into a specific tag.

Is there any way to do this on a per-project level and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [TelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer) similar to this:

```
internal class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {           
        telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("mytagname", "mytagvalue");
    }
}
```

Register it:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using CustomInitializer.Telemetry;
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyTelemetryInitializer>();
}
```

This will ensure that every telemetry item emitted by this app will have above tag.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!